# FATAL: Module rtc not found

Tags: kernel, upstart, nginx

Upstart gives "unknown job" error when I try to start the server with `$ start <my-app-name>`. I found this in the logs:

```
z@ubuntu:/var/log/upstart$ sudo zcat module-init-tools.log.1.gz
FATAL: Module rtc not found.
```

Can you help me understand how I can fix this? From my search online it seems this is related to a missing module in the kernel??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is normal, it is not related to your `start <my-app-name>` command. This happens because in `/etc/modules` this module `rtc` is listed and is does not exist.

So every system start upstart tries to load this module and fails.

There is already a bug reported for this. (see [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kmod/+bug/1240935))